# Filtering a UITableView from NSFetchedResultsController and Core Data with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a `UITableView` using `NSFetchedResultsController` to display a list of users.
I added a `UISegmentedControl` to switch between my full list of users and only my active users.

To get my list of users, I use `fetchedResultsController` :

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    if (self.barSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"active == YES"]];
    }

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

To perform an update of the tableview when clicking on the `UISegmentedControl`, I use `segmentedControlIndexChanged` :

```
-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged{
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self fetchedResultsController];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But I'm not sure I'm doing this right.
Could you say me if this is the right way to filter a `UITableView` with `NSFetchedResultsController` ?

I also wanted to know if it is possible to filter a list with an animation ? 
Exactly like in the iPhone Phone App when in the Recents Tab, it switch from all calls to missed calls ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is something not working? How do you currently handle the FRC delegate methods?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work fine. I too using the same thing without any issues.

Coming to animation you can do them in its delegate methods,

Check [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

`self.fetchedResultsController = nil;` is a reasonable way to invalidate a property.

But you should **delete this weird `[self fetchedResultsController];` line.**

`[self.tableView reloadData];` will call your delegate which should access `fetchedResultsController` property  (if you're using `_fetchedResultsController` variable in your datasource methods, that would be an anti-pattern).

> filter a list with an animation

Prepare a list of rows to hide and send

```
     [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: ... withRowAnimation:...]
```

instead of `reloadData`.